# Purpose of providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" in EF Designer connection string

Tags: mysql, .net, entity-framework

I created an entity framework designer diagram and when I tried to generate the database, I had to set up a connection to my password protected MySql database. I chosed not to include sensitive connection data into the automatically generated string, and so I got a connnection string without password in the App.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DomainContainer" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Domain.csdl|res://*/Domain.ssdl|res://*/Domain.msl;provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;server=localhost;User Id=the_user;database=the_db&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Obviously, if I then instantiate the ObjectContext like this:

```
var dc = new DomainContainer();
```

I get an exception ("The underlying provider failed on Open."), because MySql requires authentication. If I remove the connection string from App.config, and instead change the instantiation code to:

```
var connectionString = string.Format("metadata=res://*/Domain.csdl|res://*/Domain.ssdl|res://*/Domain.msl;provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider connection string=\";server=localhost;User Id=the_user;Password={0};database=the_db\"", password);
var dc = new DomainContainer(connectionString);
```

Then the ObjectContext is able to connect and correctly persist the changes to the database (I only tried to perform insertions as of now).

I know that this is not the recommended way of supplying a connection string by code, and instead I should use connection string builders. However I want to point out that in the process of switching from App.config supplied connection string to a code supplied one, the providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" piece of information was lost, and still the Entity Framework appears to be operating correctly. **So, is that piece of information redundant in some way?**

**Update (possibly unrelated)**

I reran the MySQL Installer to double check that the installation was fine and to add a new MySQL user without password authentication (by the way, I wasn't given such an option). Instead, MySQL Installer installed a pending update (MySQL for Visual Studio 1.0.2) which appears to have damaged my installation: now the program which used to work properly a few minutes ago raises a never seen before ArgumentException:

```
The specified store provider cannot be found in the configuration, or is not valid.
```

**Update to the update**

It looks like the installer created a few copies of the same MySQL assemblies in different directories of my system; maybe the runtime gets confused? However, adding the following to App.config solves the problem:

```
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <add name="MySQL Data Provider"
           invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"
           description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL"
           type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
```

Even though I still get an error message in the error console of Visual Studio:

```
Errore  1   Errore 175: Il provider dell'archivio specificato non è stato trovato nella configurazione oppure non è valido. C:\Users\Dario\Documents\Programming\EFTest\EFTest\Domain.edmx  7   5   EFTest
```

Which sounds like the same as the exception mentioned in the **Update**, but localized in my language.

Comment: can it be becasue you did not remove the colon - instead of `...string=\";server=localhost;User Id=the...` try `...string=\"server=localhost;User Id=the...` (note that the ';' before 'server' is now removed - it belonged to &quote; in the config file)

Comment: @Pawel very good eye, thanks for pointing that out :-) There is a leading ; in the C# version of my connection string. It doesn't seem to be the source of the problem (I assume you were addressing the issue described in the **Update**). That is only solved by adding the system.data section in the App.config, as shown in the **Update to the update**. Without that section, even with your correction I still get the store provider exception.

Comment: Yes this is becasue the MySql provider is probably not registered by default in the machine config. I encountered this when trying EF with MySql on Mono - see the blog post: http://blog.3d-logic.com/2013/04/14/entity-framework-6-on-mono/ for more details.