# How to move EF6.1 connection string from connectionStrings to an appSettings config file section?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework

I'm using Entity Framework 6.1.3, DB-first approach and SQL Server. After model generation Entity Framework include connection string in my projects app.config file in following way:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyEntities" connectionString="metadata=res:...
         provider=System.Data.SqlClient;...App=EntityFramework&quot;" 
         providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
...
<providers>      
    <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
              type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices,
              EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
</providers>
```

And basically I want to move this connection string from `connectionStrings` section to `appSettings` section, so I can use [CloudConfigurationManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.cloudconfigurationmanager.aspx) to pass [connection string](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entityclient.entityconnection.connectionstring(v=vs.110).aspx) to db context. To do so I need to properly merge `connectionString` and `providerName` attribute values.

What are `provider` part of a `connectionString` and `providerName`? Are they identify library which will be used to access database? In that case which one will be used: [this one](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient(v=vs.110).aspx), [that one](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.sqlserver.sqlproviderservices(v=vs.113).aspx) or another one? How do I specify connection string as a single string in `appSettings` section?

I've tried to put only `connectionString` attribute value in `appSettings`, and all seems to work normal by the moment. But why then there is a `providerName` attribute at all?

There are several [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18950999/purpose-of-providername-system-data-entityclient-in-ef-designer-connection-str), but none of them seems to fully answer to this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't *need* the providerName. It's just a piece of data that goes along with the connection string that says what provider should be used with the connection string. It's useful for tools that can utilize multiple providers, such as the [`SqlDataSource`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource(v=vs.110).aspx) control. The default is normally `SqlClient` anyways. The bottom line is if you don't include it and everything still works, then don't worry about including it.

Comment: That is a different kinds of 'provider' specified in providerName and provider part of a connection string attribute?

Comment: @Leonid So what's your question?

Comment: I wondering why they aren't same in this case? `provider=System.Data.SqlClient` within connectionString and `providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"`attribute value.

Comment: @Leonid Because EF can utilize multiple providers, not just SQL. The connection string is *for* EF, but you can think of it as having an inner connection string and provider so it knows where to get the data from.